# Is Google Lighthouse auditing using the local network?

Tags: google-chrome, lighthouse

When using Google Lighthouse on Chrome Dev Tools, is it using the local network to evaluate the performance or running the audit on a remote server.

In summary if I am evaluating a website that uses CDNs, would I get the same results if I run an audit on chrome dev tools in Germany and in China?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58394704/2397550

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you